# Policy fallacy in a youtube video

Tags: logic

The picture of a YouTube video below suggests that out of policy A, B, or C in a 3-voter system, policy A would win. The voters ranked policies by how much they favorite them. However, if we rank policies as: #1: 3 points, rank #2: 2 points, and a rank #3: 1 point then all A, B, and C all add up to the same 6 points. (there is clearly a symmetry 3 policies, 3 people, and every combination is generated. He then states: B is favorable to C and C is favorable to A.

[image]

Just checking if I am in fact going insane. Thanks!

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, this is referred to as intransitivity of voting (or probability or dice, wherever you see it). $A$ is preferable to $B$, $B$ to $C$ and $C$ to $A$ as individual candidates.

Comment: It's a vote for A or B. There aren't "points" as part of the vote. Person 1 and person 3 will vote for A, because both rank A higher than B. Thus A "wins" by majority.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not about ranking the three policies globally, is about each voter choosing one policy over the other in a non-transitive way.

The third person will vote for A as well because given the choice to vote FOR A OR B, they rank A higher than B. The key is the narrowing of the choice to two of the options instead of three. If they voted on the three issues at the same time we know there’d be no winner, but they’re not, and their two-way choices are not transitive, which basically implies that we can get any policy chosen as long as we pair it up with the proper match.

The fact that the three policies are ranked the same “globally” is where the contrast is. Later in the video they also mention how you can achieve any policy X with a succession of policies that are accepted only by different subsets of “a half plus one” people.